# How effective is the Orion radiation protection plan?

Tags: crewed-spaceflight, radiation, deep-space, orion-spacecraft

[This](https://www.nasa.gov/feature/scientists-and-engineers-evaluate-orion-radiation-protection-plan) article gives a basic overview of the procedure for astronauts on deep space missions who need to take shelter from energetic events such as solar flares.  The shelter area strongly resembles a certain fictional spacecraft with some hidden compartments for smuggling.  Are there any currently available technical details on the warning system (HERA) or the protection provided by the shelter?  Specifically I am interested in:

1. The amount of advance warning provided by HERA.  Would Earth be able to communicate a pending event faster, provided the spacecraft were positioned advantageously for this in the solar system?  Does HERA give any lead time or is the warning essentially "you are currently being bombarded with high energy particles?"
2. Will the shelters provide complete or only partial protection from likely events for deep space missions?  Things like solar flares or CMEs are obviously more of a concern (based on likelihood) than extrasolar events.

Comment: possibly helpful https://cpaess.ucar.edu/sites/default/files/documents/sww-2018-presentations/Lee_Kerry_02.pdf and also http://www.wrmiss.org/workshops/twentyfirst/Semones.pdf